# ArrayOutOfBounds Exception

Tags: java, arrays

I have been using this - 1 resolution for a while now, and was wondering if there is a way to correct the for loop arrayoutofbounds without the use of -1.  Please advise?

```
for(int i = 0; i < hand.length - 1 ; i++)
        {
            if(this.hand[i].getRank() == this.hand[i + 1].getRank())
                return true;
        }
```

Comment: Sure, don't use `i + 1` inside the loop.

Comment: And what is wrong with this solution?

Comment: `i+1` cause arrayindexoutof bounds

Comment: You might want to try iterating hand.length/2 times, and have i+=2 instead

Comment: I have to use i + 1 to compare the next card in the hand.  I don't know if there is any thing wrong with this solution, just wondering if there was another work around.

Comment: @user1051043 That's exactly the problem, the last index doesn't have a next to compare to.. see my anwer below and see Tim Pote's for the check

Comment: But he is iterating until `hand.length - 1`, so the last iteration will be fine..

Comment: @Chopin Yeah I think he's saying that what he has *does* work, but he wants to know if there's a better way.

Comment: Just for S&G, is there by any chance any arrarys being iterated during the getRank method?

Comment: @TimPote yes that is what I am asking.

Comment: @CDSmith no, the getRank method returns the enum type value for the rank of the card.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming rank is an `int`

```
    int prevRank = this.hand[0].getRank();
    for(int i = 1; i < hand.length; i++)
    {
        int currentRank = this.hand[i].getRank();
        if(currentRank == prevRank)
            return true;
        prevRank = currentRank;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You could check if the `i +1` element exists before trying to read from the array.

Something like this would work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < hand.length; i++)
        {   
            if(i + 1 < this.hand.length && this.hand[i].getRank() == this.hand[i + 1].getRank())
                return true;
        }
```

Though I don't think it's necessarily better than what you have already.  Perhaps one could argue that my version is more explicit, but I would say what you have already is just fine.

Comment: `this.hand.length < i + 1` will only be true when `i >= hand.length`, which it will never be because of the for loop.

Comment: You still didn't fix your condition. `i` can never equal `hand.length` because once it does, the for loop exits.

Comment: @Jeffrey Yeah I really worked myself into a backwards state having `hand.length` on the left side.  See my edits

Answer (score -2):

Remember, if you want to iterate over all the items in a collection, you can use the `for-each` form:

```
for (YourClass item : collection) {
    // do something with item
}
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/foreach.html

**EDIT:** just to show a way to use the iterator.

```
int nextToCompare = 1; // the index of the next item in the array to compare with the current item
for (Item item : this.hand) {
    if (nextToCompare < this.hand.length // checks if there is next item to compare
            && item.getRank() == this.hand[nextToCompare++].getRank()) {
        return true;
    }
}
return false;
```

One cons of this method is that it iterates trough the entire array, rather than over `n - 1` elements.

I think the method you posted is actually a good solution, in terms of efficiency and clarity.

Comment: I didn't downvote, but I'm not sure that w/o more specifics this addresses the root of the question given the OP's code snippet.

Comment: Also didn't downvote, but this *doesn't* solve the OP's issue.  They want to access the `i + 1` element will iterating over the array, which is impossible with a `for-each` loop unless you make an index.  In which case you might as well use a traditional `for` loop.

Comment: I didn't downvote too (?). But yes, later I did realize the real problem and why this is not a solution. I'm still thinking a way to improve my answer to solve the problem, but maybe it becomes the worst example ever seen. Maybe this encourages the asker to keep his actual method :P Otherwise, I'll delete my answer.

Comment: @Chopin You could essentially do what vizier's answer does: keep track of the prev element.